# Console image flickering in windows 10

Tags: c++, console-application, windows-10, doublebuffered

The following code works as expected in windows xp, but in windows 10 the image starts flickering. How do I make it work in windows 10?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

#define xMax 180
#define yMax 45
#define Fps 250

class dbconsole
{
private:
    int width, height, FPS, delay;
    HANDLE h0, h1;
    std::vector<CHAR_INFO> chiBuffer;
    bool curBuffer;
    int drawingTimer;

    void preparebuffer(HANDLE &h)
    {
        CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursor = {false, 1};
        SMALL_RECT windowRectangle = {0,0,width-1,height-1};
        h = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER,
                NULL);
        SetConsoleCursorInfo(h, &cursor);
        SetConsoleScreenBufferSize (h, {width,height});
        SetConsoleWindowInfo(h,true,&windowRectangle);
    }

public:

    dbconsole(int Width, int Height, int fps)
    {
        chiBuffer.reserve(Width*Height);
        width = Width;
        height = Height;
        FPS = fps;
        preparebuffer(h0);
        preparebuffer(h1);
        curBuffer = 0;
        drawingTimer = clock();
        for (int i = 0; i < xMax; i++) for (int j = 0; j < yMax; j++) chiBuffer[i+width*j] = {'t',16};
    }

    void depict()
    {
        SMALL_RECT srctWriteRect;
        srctWriteRect.Top = 0;
        srctWriteRect.Left = 0;
        srctWriteRect.Bottom = height-1;
        srctWriteRect.Right = width-1;
        if ((clock()-drawingTimer)*FPS>CLOCKS_PER_SEC)
        {
            if (curBuffer)
            {
                WriteConsoleOutput(h0, &chiBuffer[0], {width,height}, {0,0}, &srctWriteRect);
                SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(h0);
            }
            else
            {
                WriteConsoleOutput(h1, &chiBuffer[0], {width,height}, {0,0}, &srctWriteRect);
                SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(h1);
            }
            curBuffer=!curBuffer;
            drawingTimer = clock();
        }
    }

};

int main(void)
{
    dbconsole myConsole = dbconsole(xMax,yMax,Fps);
    while (true) myConsole.depict();
}
```

I want the program to show black letters 't' on blue background, but with no flickering and with double buffering

Comment: I remember having a similar problem long before windows 10... I'm not sure, but I think it was the XP era. For me, the solution was to write an update routine for the current screen buffer instead of frequently switching buffers, however I did not go for 250 fps there...

Comment: Switching to 60 fps doesn't help.
Also, this drawing worked for windows 8.
And I want to use those consoles to display some information where I may need do redraw everyting in an instant, so double buffering seems necessary.

Comment: ofcourse... 60fps is probably your monitor refresh rate anyway. You should go down to 1fps so you can evaluate the effect of a single refresh. As long as you can see any effect, its going to flicker with faster updates.

Comment: With 1 fps no flickering occurs, but a cursor appears in the top-left corner, while I was sure that the line CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cursor = {false, 1}; was supposed to hide it.

Comment: Well then, I have no idea how to hide a cursor in windows 10 but I guess you can figure it out now that you know what to look for ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after looking into the problem anyway, here is an answer.

`CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO` is defined as first `DWORD dwSize` and second `BOOL  bVisible` but you use it as if first and second member where the other way round. Consequently, `SetConsoleCursorInfo` fails with return value `0` and `GetLastError` returns 87, which is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` ([See error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Correctly disabling the cursor should solve the problem, though I don't have windows 10 available for testing.

Comment: Thank you, the cursor has disappeared, it is working at 1fps, but the image is still flickering at 40fps